# Trouble parsing .yaml files with powershell

Tags: powershell, yaml

I basically wrote a script to parse json objects and pop certain information out of the json file into an excel doc. Well those files were originally .yaml, and I converted them using a tool. I found that some have incorrect formatting which didnt allow all of them to convert to json format. So I installed the powershell-yaml module and attempted to use **ConvertFrom-YAML** and the script is not pulling the same information as my json script. If theres a way to pull that data using json, but keep the files as a .yaml in their original directory, feel free to share!

Working JSON Code:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\powershell-scripts\spConnections" -Filter *.json -PipelineVariable file | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_ -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).PSObject.Properties.Value | Select-Object @(
        @{ N = 'FileName'; E = { $file.Name }}, 'Name', 'entity_id', 'contact_info', 'sp_endpoint'
    )
} | Export-Csv "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\powershell-scripts\dataexports\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

YAML Code that doesnt work:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\targetfolder" -Recurse -Filter *.yaml -PipelineVariable file | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_ -Raw | ConvertFrom-Yaml).PSObject.Properties.Value | Select-Object @(
        @{ N = 'FileName'; E = { $file.Name }}, 'Name', 'entity_id', 'contact_info', 'sp_endpoint'
    )
} | Export-Csv "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\powershell-scripts\dataexports\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample .yaml output:

```
---
  sfg_hhh::production::standard_sp_connections:
  - name: RRRRR
    entity_id: WWWWWW
    contact_info: ggggg@ggggg.com
    sp_endpoint: CCCCC
    base_index: 0
    sso_initialization_and_signature_policy:
      signing_certificate_id: EEEEE 
      sp_initiated: 
        require_signed_authn_requests: false
    authentication_policy_contracts:
      - LDAPUser
    attribute_contract:
```

Intended Output:
[image]

Output Currently:
[image]

Comment: Please give a sample of the YAML input file that can be used to produce the intended output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the first property in the yaml isn't very nice to handle :/
So you have to bypass it as you've already tried too.

I've got a little trick to pivot the object received from ConvertFrom-Yaml, by passing it through JSON.

```
$files = get-childitem "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\powershell-scripts\spConnections" `
    -Filter "*.yaml" -Recurse -File

[array]$array = @()
foreach ($file in $files){
    $object = (
        get-content $file | ConvertFrom-Yaml | 
        ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json
    ).PSobject.Properties.Value | select name,contact_info
    $object = $object | Select @{l='filename'; e={$file.Name}}, *
    $array += $object
}

# $array | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation
$array | Export-Csv -Path ./path.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Edit: Changed to fetching all YAML-files below the current folder.

Comment: This one has me a little confused. I see what you did, but running it in a terminal doesn't return any sort of result, I tried to add a `| export-csv -path /path.csv`  after `$array | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation` and that also doesnt populate any data into the csv file. Perhaps my formatting is wrong?

Comment: Are we using the same YAML-module? Mine is `powershell-yaml` version 0.4.2. (Just noticed that current version is v0.4.3)

Comment: Yep! I am using that module. I think I messed up my og script in the post. The `$files` actually points to a directory in which there are multiple folders with multiple .yaml files, will that get-item handle that without specifying `-recurse` and `-file`?

Comment: No. I'm only targeting a single folder. So you need to fetch the files your way.

Comment: In that case, would the best method be to use the original `Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\targetfolder" -Recurse -Filter *.yaml` in my original script?

Comment: Yes. You could add the switch `-File` as well just to make sure. It's highly unlikely that any folder will be called <folder>.yaml. But you never know.

Comment: I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Interesting. The script is now failing on the get-content piece. When it loops, its saying the files dont exist. `get-content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\ITS34\appdev\configurations\hhh.yaml' because it does not exist.
At line:6 char:9`. This is super weird because the file path listed in the error output isnt referenced at all in this script.

Comment: Is the file active. I.e. is another system trying to write to it currently? Some systems might even replace the file instead of appending.

Comment: I am using an offline clone of a file directory, so no applications should be writing into that folder. I also tried running this via .ps1 directly, as well as booting up PS ISE and running, and still get the same error with an incorrect directory. Very weird.

Comment: Or do you perhaps have links (shortcuts) in the path below that sidetracks the recursive function?

But it could simply by a corrupt NTFS file system (most likely), since it's a duplicate you can just as well try repairing it first.

Comment: Would it be possible to use a foreach-object loop instead of an array? I think that may be where this is getting mixed up. PS doesnt know what to do with the $file variable perhaps?

Comment: It is a foreach-loop ;) Since you need the filename to be part of the output, and I wasn't sure how many contacts you have per file, each row has to have the filename added somehow. There are propable other ways, but this is how I usually go about myslef.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by adding .pspath after $file. It appears by default, PS will reference the fileID in the location of your terminal, not code, so adding that extension correctly changes the output.

Comment: Glad you found the solution.